# Decide if there exist supspaces $W,U$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $f(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)=(x_2+x_3,x_3,0,0) \ $ decide if there exists invariant, two dimensional subspaces $W,U$ of $\mathbb{R}^4$ such that $\mathbb{R}^4 = W \oplus U$

My question is if there exist a systematic way of finding two dimensional subspaces?  Here I try by trial and error method but I failed.

I found eigenvalue is $\lambda=0$ and $V_{(0)}=span((1,0,0,0),(0,0,0,1))$ but don't know how to use it

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "invariant"?

Comment: Do you know how to find the Jordan normal form of a matrix?  Specifically of the matrix that represents $f$?

Comment: Definition: Let $f \in L(V)$ and $U$ subspace of $V$ then $U$ is ivariant under $V$ if for $v \in U \implies f(v) \in U$       @Jim Unfortunately not, it should be possible to do without jordan form

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the cleanest way to do it because it's basically unpacking the Jordan normal form argument, but it'll work:

- Assume $U$ and $V$ exist, first show that if $v \in V$, $u \in U$, and $u + v \in \ker f$ then $u, v \in \ker f$.  So $\ker f = (U \cap \ker f) \oplus (V \cap \ker f)$.
- Use $f^3 = 0$ to show that both $U \cap \ker f$ and $V \cap \ker f$ are nonempty, so they must each be $1$-dimensional.
- If $U$ is $2$-dimensional and $U \cap \ker f$ is $1$-dimensional then show that $U$ must be spanned by $u_1, u_2$ where $f(u_1) = u_2$ and $f(u_2) = 0$.  Note this means $f^2(U) = 0$.
- Finally, by symmetry $f^2(V) = 0$ so $f^2 = 0$.  Show that $f^2 \neq 0$.  This is a contradiction.